# Cannot figure out how to fix blank xc.workspace file in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods, xcode14

This morning while attempting to commit something happened that deleted all the files in my project's folder. Below are the steps that caused the issue and where I am at.  I'm nervous to move forward for fear of making the problem worse.  Any help is much appreciated.

Using Xcode 14 Beta 2

My project was a mixture of a few Swift Package libraries as well as 1 cocoapod (which is why I need to use xc.workspace to manage my project.

```
(1) I tried to commit changes in Summer22Betas (branch) 
(2) I saw that I had no files in the left tap in Xcode
(3) I opened the project folder in Finder and saw I had no files (my files are sync’d to the Dropbox cloud) 
(4) I went to Dropbox.com saw that all my files were deleted and restored them 
(5) if I open the xc.workspace there are no files (like there were after I tried to commit) and it says "the operation couldn't be performed" 
(6) if I open the xcodeproj the files were all there but I cannot build (presumably because my pods are missing, or because I have pods and need to be able to open the XC.Workspace).
```

I also get this error `Package.resolved file is corrupted or malformed; fix or delete the file to continue: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to parse empty data." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to parse empty data.})))`

The only pod I was using is the iOS Charts library but it is in my pods folder in Finder

Should I delete the current XC.Workspace and try reinstalling cocoapods?
Or don’t delete it but try reinstalling cocopods?

Comment: "my files are sync'd to the Dropbox cloud" note that that situation is totally untenable: you _cannot_ keep a Git repository in a dropbox-sync'd folder. Dropbox will destroy the repository (and it sounds to me like it did)

Comment: @matt I can access both branches which aren't corrupt or anything, the problem is just I can't build in Xcode because of the XC.Workspace problem.  Definitely won't use Dropbox in the future though.

Comment: Yeah, at this point I think your best bet is (1) take thing out of the dropbox and (2) reset hard back to the last working commit